# Dynamically added RatingBar does not show up

Tags: android, view, ratingbar

I am adding a RatingBar to a linear layout dynamically. The Rating bar is not visible of a phone where as it is visible in a tablet.
Following is the code for creating the RatingBar.

```
    View newWidget = new RatingBar(appContext);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    newWidget.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    ((RatingBar) newWidget).setStepSize(1.0f);
```

Comment: you haven't added layout params to view

Comment: forgot to add that piece @VivekMishra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(context, null, android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall);
```

Try to set style for rating bar before loading its view runtime. I hope it will work for you. Thanks!!!

Comment: works when i set style as android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall but it does not work if the style is set as android.R.attr.ratingBarStyle. I don't want the small widget

Comment: Ok, try with your own style for rating bar.